# T-SQL FTP using xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, ftp, xp-cmdshell

I am using the below code snippet to FTP simple text files from a Windows Server 2003 / SQL Server 2005 database to a BULL FTP site and am getting some corruption on the BULL end.

```
select @cmd = 'ftp -s:' + @workdir + @workfilename
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, NO_OUTPUT
```

The text file contains SEP490067 but when this is opened on the BULL it appears like this ..S.E.P.4.9.0.0.6.7..

I have seen something like this before when sending files using an SSIS FTP component and switching the IsTransferAscii switch to True fixes the problem. The question I have is doe you have to set another commands line switch in the FTP command above to sent the files using ASCII rather than Binary?

Here is the fully TSQL

```
USE [JCB_QSmart]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[FTP_PutFile]    Script Date: 06/14/2012 08:56:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[FTP_PutFile]
@FTPServer  varchar(128) ,
@FTPUser    varchar(128) ,
@FTPPWD     varchar(128) ,
@FTPPath    varchar(128) ,
@FTPFileName    varchar(128) ,
@SourcePath varchar(128) ,
@SourceFile varchar(128) ,
@workdir    varchar(128),
    @ShowOutput as bit = 0
as

declare @cmd varchar(1000)
declare @workfilename varchar(128)

    select @workfilename = 'ftpcmd.txt'

    -- deal with special characters for echo commands
    select @FTPServer = replace(replace(replace(@FTPServer, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
    select @FTPUser = replace(replace(replace(@FTPUser, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
    select @FTPPWD = replace(replace(replace(@FTPPWD, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
    select @FTPPath = replace(replace(replace(@FTPPath, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')

    select  @cmd = 'echo '                  + 'open ' + @FTPServer
            + ' > ' + @workdir + @workfilename
    exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
    select  @cmd = 'echo '                  + @FTPUser
            + '>> ' + @workdir + @workfilename
    exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
    select  @cmd = 'echo '                  + @FTPPWD
            + '>> ' + @workdir + @workfilename
    exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
    select  @cmd = 'echo '                  + 'put ' + @SourcePath + @SourceFile + ' ' + @FTPPath + @FTPFileName
            + ' >> ' + @workdir + @workfilename
    exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
    select  @cmd = 'echo '                  + 'quit'
            + ' >> ' + @workdir + @workfilename
    exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

    select @cmd = 'ftp -s:' + @workdir + @workfilename

    create table #a (id int identity(1,1), s varchar(1000))
    insert #a
    exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, NO_OUTPUT

    select id, ouputtmp = s from #a
```

Comment: Please don't do this.  Use SSIS or something.

Comment: The complexity of the business logic before the send does not suit SSIS otherwise I would have used it... Sometimes SSIS is not the right platform for a task.

Comment: You can write code in SSIS.  What you're proposing is to make SQL server do something that it's not supposed to do.  XP_CMDSHELL should be a last resort - IMHO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you use the `-s` switch for ftp you should put the `ascii`-command in your workfile right after you connected to the FTP server.

**EDIT:**

So in your StoredProc you have to add the following line right before the line that contains the `'put '` command:

```
select  @cmd = 'echo ' + 'ascii > ' + @workdir + @workfilename
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Code should include additional >

```
select  @cmd = 'echo ' + 'ascii >> ' + @workdir + @workfilename
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Dont using ftp:// on parameter X @FTPServer, just enter the ip address or domain. Like,

```
echo open 10.16.22.21 >
```